# How to type the letter ï , i with diaeresis or i-umlaut in math mode on LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, accents

How to type the letter  ï , i with diaeresis or i-umlaut in math mode on LaTeX?

Comment: Please provide some information about the use case you have in mind for `ï` in math mode. Would you like the letter to be rendered in italic/slanted mode or in roman/upright mode?

Answer (score 4):

I would give `$\ddot{\imath}$` a try.

[image]

Note that `$i$` and `$\dot{\imath}$` don't produce the same output. However, the difference may not be readily apparent to most readers. In fact, I would suspect that most readers will never pick up on the differences in the outputs of `$i$` and `$\dot{\imath}$` or, for that matter, the outputs of `$j$` and `$\dot{\jmath}$`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$i \quad \imath \quad \dot{\imath} \quad \ddot{\imath}$
\end{document}
```